# how to query data from google spreadsheet into html form

Tags: html

I'm building an html page (sort of a data collection kiosk)to print out a production ticket. I want to query from my google spreadsheet all the rows that meet some criteria and select a last row's number field to calculate the difference from the new row to be inserted. example: total = newrow-lastrow.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides [APIs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) to interact with spreadsheets. This one, for example, allows you to read a range of values:

> https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

The page includes code samples in a variety of different languages.